# cakephp - css positioning issue with getting submit button and text input on same line AND replacing the button with an image

Tags: html, css, cakephp

I've managed to get my submit button and my input onto the same line in cakephp, but when I've gone to replace the boring grey submit button with an image the two no longer line up. Instead the input appears 8px below where it used to and the image appears at the right height.

```
<div class="searchForm">
    <?php
        echo $form->create('User');
        echo $form->input('Search for a friend\'s page', array('div'=>false));
        $options = array('type'=>'image','src' => 'img/searchbutton.gif','div' =>false);
        echo $form->end($options);
    ?>
</div>
```

here's the css:

```
label{display:block;}
input[type=text]{width:255px;height:30px;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:3px;background:url(../img/formfieldbg.gif) repeat-x;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;}
```

all that outputs:

```
<div class="searchForm">
<form id="UserDisplayForm" method="post" action="/cakeproject/users/display" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" /></div>
<label for="UserSearchForAFriend'sPage">Search For A Friend's Page</label>
<input name="data[User][Search for a friend's page]" type="text" id="UserSearchForAFriend&#039;sPage" />
<input type="image" src="img/searchbutton.gif" value="Submit" /></form> 
</div>
```

Can any kind soul point me in the right direction?

Comment: The cause probably lies in your input[type=image] image size. Can't really help you without its size too.

Comment: Hi there Kraz, thanks for answering, I didn't spot you'd left a comment till just now. The size of the image is 35px

Answer (score 1):

I was partly wrong, partly right in my comment :

The problem seems to be that `input[type=text]` is on `vertical-align:bottom;`
While `input[type=image]` is on `vertical-align:top;`

So, add either line in your css :

```
input[type=image] {vertical-align: bottom;}
```

**OR**

```
input[type=text] {vertical-align:top;}
```

The result is not exactly the same, but both input look more *inline* in both case (on is more like a top-align and the other is more like a center-align).

Comment: Kraz, thank you so much! You are a genius! How did you figure that out? Just by counting pixels?

Comment: Np! I put the problematic input (text+image) in a `<div>` and I put a border on that div (and looked at those input size). Both item weren't vertically-aligned, so I toyed around with different css properties (display, padding, margin...) till I found the one that made the alignment problematic.